# Phabricator Plugin differential not work

Tags: git, automatic-ref-counting, diff, phabricator, arcanist

I install phabricator in VM, phabricator reads the git repository that is on another server, when I open the commit and go down to see the code it crashes on loading...

what should happen -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjhGX.jpg

what's happening - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvFKh.png

Comment: Do you have something in the logs ?